# Выбрать записи, в которых сочетание полей двойственно

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица вида

```
   Column   |  Type   |
------------+---------+
 id         | integer |
 title      | text    |
 conference | text    |
 location   | text    |
```

Задача: выбрать те строки, в которых для одного и того же `conference` указаны разные `location`.
Пример:

```
  conference   |  location  
---------------+------------
 STOC          | Zurich
 SenSys        | Edinburgh
 CHI           | Copenhagen
 STOC          | Adelaide
 IPSN          | Edinburgh
 ICPR          | Brisbane
 ICPR          | Milan
 AAMAS(Agents) | Amsterdam
 NIPS          | Stockholm
 NIPS          | Stockholm
```

Из данной таблицы должны быть выбраны STOC и ICPR. NIPS не должен быть выбран, потому что локация совпадает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
join table_name t2 using(conference)
where t1.location <> t2.location;
```

Comment: Я бы добавил DISTINCT - если для одного conference нароется более чем 2 location, будет куча дублей.